# Jwplayer play button not working

Tags: jwplayer

In JWplayer whenever video is loaded, it will show "Play" button icon at the center of video to start video.

But clicking on play button is not starting the video.

Instead, if I click on any place around the "Play" button it works correctly. 
I am not getting how to play video on "Play" button click?
Thanks

Below is my code

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer(divId);

        playerInstance.setup({
        androidhls: true,
        playlist: [{
            image: thumb,
            sources: [
            {  // for browsers/HLS
           // file: mediaUrl,
            type: "hls" 
            },
            ],
        }],
        autostart : false,

        primary: 'html5',
        stretching: "uniform",
        width: "100%",
        stagevideo: false,

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use older version of JW Player it solved my issue

Comment: You might at least add version information about working and non-working versions so that this answer remains useful even after some time.

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug with Chrome 55 that was causing this problem with the JW Player play button. This was recently fixed, so please give your page a try using the latest production release JW 7.8.

Comment: Thanks, I will try JW 7.8

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a bug in chrome 55 and jwplayer 7.7.4

Add the following style to the page:

`.jw-display-icon-container {
   pointer-events: all !important;
 }`

Pointer events were disabled for the buttons and above styles enable it.

Answer (score 0):

This fix worked for me

```
.jw-display-icon-container {
  pointer-events: inherit !important;
}
```

Thanks to Aman Kanoria for this fix.
https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/16768225-play-button-doesn-t-work-